# How can I find files in ceph rgw without access in 60 days?

Tags: ceph

I have 2pe files in ceph rgw bucket.
How can I find files in ceph rgw without access (atime) in 60 days ( not modify time)

Answer (score 0):

The S3 standard does not include access time meta information in its store. Please see [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51839850/1195050) concerning S3 storage.

So to answer your question: access time is not defined in the [S3 standard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html).

But you could probably synthesise this information yourself by parsing the access logs if available. But yeah. That requires some scripting.